# C++11: Type of string literal is "array of the appropriate number of const characters"

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, constants

C++11: Type of string literal is "array of the appropriate number of const characters";

"Bohr" therefore would be of type `const char[5]`

```
void f()
{
 char* p = "Plato"; // error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard code
 p[4] = 'e';        // error: assignment to const
}
```

(which is a short excerpt of "The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup (4th Ed.)" on p. 176 in 7.3.2 "String Literals")
yet my compiler (Dev-C++11 5.6.2) with either settings of ISO-C++11 or GNU-C++11 doesn't warn or break compilation at

```
const char a[5] = "Bohr";
const char *b = "Bohr";
```

---

Furthermore, Question #2 at cppquiz.org also doesn't mention any compiler breakage or any other problems with this: http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/2

> **What is the output of the below program in C+++11?**
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
>
> void f(const std::string &) { std::cout << 1; }
>
> void f(const void *) { std::cout << 2; }
>
> int main() {
>   f("foo");
>   const char *bar = "bar";
>   f(bar);
> }
> ```

Before writing the author, I wanted to ask for advice here; I hope you can help me?

Edit: The line

```
char* p = "Plato"; // error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard code
```

should, as is commented, not be valid in C++-11-standard code, according to the latest book from the official creator of the language, but in

```
const char *b = "Bohr";
```

there appears to be no problem in the quiz as well the compiler?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's not clear *why* you expect things to break. Are you confused about automatic array-to-pointer conversion? Are you expecting the apparent attempt to assign an array to another array to be invalid?

Comment: Array types decay to pointers anyway when passed around.

Comment: Why do you think the compiler should complain about your last example?

Comment: He has a problem with Stroustroup's statement "...error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard", because modern compilers do not generate errors on this code.

Comment: Yes, exactly - that's my problem here. ^^

Comment: @SChepurin "Modern" compilers can be trivially instructed to emit a warning such as `warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated`, and told to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: But I got maximum warning level set already in Dev-C++ 5.6.2 and there are no whatsoever warnings.

Comment: @Starhowl I guess you don't really have maximum warning level, or your compiler is quite old. I get warnings with gcc 4.8.2 (I am sure I got them since 4.6) and clang 3.4.

Comment: Just as an additional Note: VS2013 doesn't give a warning either

Comment: @MikeMB Yes it does, turn your warning level up to /W4

Comment: @Praetorian: I did (I also checked /Wall) - could there be any other option influencing the warning behavior?

Comment: @MikeMB You're right, I can't get it to emit warnings either. I'm pretty sure I've seen older versions do that, so this must be yet another improvement from the VC team. That compiler never fails to surprise you.

Answer (score 2):

The type of string literal `"Bohr"` is indeed `const char[5]`.

However, it can be implicitly casted to `const char *` due to

**§ 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]**

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the ﬁrst element of the array.

**Edit:**

I didn't realize your confusion was from Bjarne's statement about `// error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard code`. Well, compilers need to stay backwards-compatible so they don't throw an error, but they do give you a warning. His claim isn't wrong however, since as far as the language standard goes, by C++11 rules it is an error.

From clang for example:

> warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
>         [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]

and from gcc:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: Alright, I - of sorts - do understand that, but why did the author then write "error, but accepted in pre-C++11-standard code"?

Comment: Updated answer to justify his claims

Comment: @Starhowl To clarify, it is an error, it always was, but it was allowed before, and is deprecated now. The reason it was allowed was probably C backwards compatibility.

Comment: @juanchopanza - That is what he (an many others) has a problem with when starts to learn C++ - "...it is an error, it always was, but it was allowed before". It takes time and experience to get to the point that "it was allowed for C backwards compatibility."